EnsureDispatch("PowerPoint.Application") does not generate msoShapeXxxxxxx constants
According to documentation, if you use win32com Python Library as follow
import win32com.client as win32

and use the following instructions
# Start PowerPoint and generate constants
PowerPointApp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("PowerPoint.Application")   PowerPointApp.Visible = True
mso = win32.constants

Office should generate in a directory like
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.10\91493440-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263Bx0x2x12

a file called __init__.py that should contains all PowerPoint API constants.
It does, but the constants for the types of shapes, as for instance msoShapeRectangle or msoShapeOval are missing.
Any idea why? Should I do anything else?
I use the latest version of Office, latest version of pywin32.
